# Hide/Show "Scroll To Top" button based on WebView's scroll

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm making an UWP app that contains a WebView and I want to implement a simple "Scroll to top" button, I have already made de code behind this button and it works:

```
        private async void ToTopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        var ScrollToTopString = @"var int = setInterval(function() { 
        window.scrollBy(0, -36);

        if( window.pageYOffset === 0 )
            clearInterval(int);
        }, 0.1);";
        await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { ScrollToTopString });
        }
```

But now I want to only show the button if the user need it, so if the WebView scroll is on top the button should be hidden and viceversa...I've research and I haven't found anything. Can anyone help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to only show the button if the user need it, so if the WebView scroll is on top the button should be hidden and viceversa.

The WebView's scroll bar is not accessible to the app directly, because it is a part of the embedded Edge browser view. SO you may need use the script to monitor the scroll operation by [onscroll event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp) and also invoke the script by `InvokeScriptAsync`.

And then you may need to notify your uwp app if the scroll is on the top. For this, you may need to use [`ScriptNotify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_ScriptNotify) event of `Webview`. A hosted HTML page can fire the `ScriptNotify` event in your Windows Store app when the page calls `window.external.notify` and passes a string parameter.

But pay attention about the note of `ScriptNotify`:

> To prevent malicious scripts from exploiting this event, be sure to enable it only for trusted URIs.

You must include the page's URI in the ApplicationContentUriRules section of the app manifest. (You can do this in Visual Studio on the Content URIs tab of the Package.appxmanifest designer.) The URIs in this list must use HTTPS and may contain subdomain wildcards (for example, "https://.microsoft.com"), but they can't contain domain wildcards (for example, "https://.com" and "https://.").

Here is the completed sample:

```
<Button x:Name="ToTopButton" Content="to top" Click="ToTopButton_Click"></Button>
<WebView x:Name="MyWebView"  Height="500" Width="400" Source="https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/"  ScriptNotify="MyWebView_ScriptNotify" NavigationCompleted="MyWebView_NavigationCompleted"></WebView>
```

Code behind

```
private async void ToTopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ScrollToTopString = @"var int = setInterval(function(){window.scrollBy(0, -36); if( window.pageYOffset === 0 ) clearInterval(int); }, 0.1);";
    await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { ScrollToTopString });
}

private void MyWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{      
    var result = e.Value;
    if (result == "true")
    {
        ToTopButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        ToTopButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
} 

private async void MyWebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    string addlistener = @"window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
                          function myFunction()
                          {if( window.pageYOffset === 0 )  window.external.notify('true'); else window.external.notify('false');} "; 
    await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { addlistener });
    //first time check
    var firstnotify = "if( window.pageYOffset === 0 )  window.external.notify('true'); else window.external.notify('false')";
    await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { firstnotify });
}
```

Frequently notify may influence the performance so this is not very recommended unless you must use the feature.

Comment: Thanks! This work for me but I'll want to know how hard does this impact the overall performance of the app.

Comment: @PabloJiménezPascual, I think it dependency on how frequently the user scroll.  If only few pages using this may not influence more.